# Magento 2.1.2 "Invalid option value" when importing configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, import, csv

I'm trying to import configurable products into Magento 2.1.2. I have already imported the simple products.

When trying to import the configurable products, it seems to happen randomly. In total I have 1930 rows, but the above issue only occurs with 623.

So far, I have:

- Checked the configurable_variations exist
- The imported products have a quantity above 0
- The products are enabled
- Checked all error logs - no related entries.
- Encoded the .csv in UTF-8-BOM

What is causing this issue? Or where can I find more data to try and solve it?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to import, saved as a .csv:

https://ufile.io/6a45

Thanks for your time!

Edit: I can provide .csv entries in plain text, they are very long so I didn't include initially.

Comment: Please update if you have fixed this issue

Comment: @StevieG I reverted to Magento 1.9.3.2, solved my issue

Comment: To fix this issue you needed to delete all the products and reimport